# How do I lookup the details of a transaction, given the transaction ID?

Tags: transactions, transaction-verification

I transferred BTC from GDAX to Binance.  I have the transaction ID.  How do I find out the status of the transfer.  GDAX reports transfer complete.  Thanks.

Comment: Check https://blockexplorer.com/

Comment: I have this same question. https://www.blockonomics.co is pretty cool (in addition to blockexplorer and others mentioned) once we know the BTC transaction ID, but right now I only know my Gdax transfer ID, which doesn't seem to help me.

Comment: Here are other people having the same problem with GDAX in the past month saying that transactions can take hours or days to get confirmed in their destination: https://www.reddit.com/r/GDAX/comments/7c5q81/can_i_use_gdax_transfer_id_to_find_my_transaction/

Comment: I found the answer. If it helps you, please upvote and click the checkmark to accept it: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/66041/36024

Answer (score 2):

**I found where GDAX shows the transaction hash!**

1. Visit https://www.gdax.com/accounts
2. Click a coin on the left (BTC, BCH, ETH, or LTC).
3. Instead of staying on the "History" tab (which is probably where you see Transfer ID for each transfer), click "Transfers" in the top right.
4. Then click each "withdraw" row to expand it, and you'll see its transaction hash.

For example, I'm able to find the hash of an LTC that I just transferred, and then I can browse to https://bchain.info/LTC/tx/4a857bc76d31c801dbc1aac33c4940cd11401f7f7401dfd6e05dfcf43af8867e and see that it has already been confirmed twice.

Comment: Correction, first go to "Accounts", then select your coin, then click the "Transfers" tab.

Comment: @bart Good point. Updated my answer.

Comment: Only show hash after transfer has been completed :(

Comment: Wow, I'm interested to look back on this answer of mine, and by now I don't even remember what gdax.com was, and it's now unavailable, as is bchain.info.

Answer (score 1):

The GDAX transaction ID doesn't seem to be helpful in tracking unconfirmed transfers (the kind you most want to track). Instead, use the recipient address with blockchain.info.

Just pop the recipient BTC address (the one you transferred to) into the search on http://blockchain.info and you should see the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for it on a publicly available blockchain explorer. Some examples:

- https://blockchain.info/
- https://blockexplorer.com/
- https://chainflyer.bitflyer.jp/
- https://live.blockcypher.com/
- https://www.blocktrail.com/BTC

Comment: Gdax.com only seems to provide a hyphenated Transfer ID rather than a BTC transaction ID, so I don't think those sites help.

Comment: I found the answer: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/66041/36024